# Example for DevExpress QuantumGrid Master-Detail

Tags: delphi, master-detail

Where can I find a **basic example** of using QuantumGrid 6 of Developer Express in a Master-detail relation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DevExpress QuantumGrid page](http://www.devexpress.com) have a very complex and large collection of samples that you can use.
Visit the [Knowledge Base section](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/) and search for your question.

it's sure that you find somethig usefull.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of the Master-Detail Tutorial in the help file?

You should find it in "$(DXVCL)\ExpressQuantumGrid 6\Help\EXPRESSQUANTUMGRID6.HLP" I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You need just add a level to your marter data and a sub-level to your detail data.
After do that, select your detail level and set DataControler's properties to:

1- MasterKeyFieldNames to PK of master data;
2- DetailKeyFieldNames to FK of detail data.

If you want handle records you still need define KeyFieldNames with the PK to both levels.

To see a detailed explanation about how do it, open EXPRESSQUANTUMGRID6.HLP e search for "master-detail".